# How to set default activationStrategy in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Aurelia normally ignores any changes in the querystring.

It is possible to set the `activationStrategy` to `invoke-lifecycle` in the VM so it will re-run the all the life cycles in the VM when the querystring changes.

To prevent littering my code (placing it in every VM) i want to set the default `activationStrategy` to `invoke-lifecycle`.

In the interface it's explained that it **is** possible, but how to set it?
https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/master/src/interfaces.js

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### On the ViewModel

(I misread your question at first too, but I'm leaving this in for completeness)

Place a method `determineActivationStrategy()` on the ViewModel and from there you can return the name or type of the activation strategy you wish to use. Example:

```
determineActivationStrategy() {
    return "invoke-lifecycle";
}
```

The strings `"invoke-lifecycle"` or `"replace"` will work. You can also use the typed version by importing the enum `activationStrategy` and returing `activationStrategy.replace` / `activationStrategy.invokeLifecycle`. They work the same.

#### In the RouteConfig

Or, as stated by Marton (who gave this answer before I did), you can put it directly in route config as the property `activationStrategy`.

This approach is better suited if the strategy does not depend on any particular state of your ViewModel and you don't wish to litter your view model with this stuff.

#### invoke-lifecycle vs. replace

In your question you say you want to

> re-run the all the life cycles in the VM

Note that `invoke-lifecycle` reuses the existing ViewModel and will only invoke the router activation lifecycle, which is as follows:

1. `canDeactivate()`
2. `deactivate()`
3. `canActivate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction)`
4. `activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction)`

Whereas `replace` will throw away the existing ViewModel and invoke the whole ViewModel lifecycle again **on top of** the router activation lifecycle:

1. `canDeactivate()`
2. `deactivate()`
3. `detached()`
4. `unbind()`
5. (new instance): `constructor()`
6. `canActivate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction)`
7. `activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction)`
8. `created(owningView, thisView)`
9. `bind(bindingContext, overrideContext)`
10. `attached()`

So if you really want to run all the ViewModel lifecycle steps, you'll need to use `replace`.

Comment: Using 'determineActivationStrategy' was my first thought as well. Then I realized that Vijay wants to avoid placing it into every VM. Your answer has more details, so +1! :)

Comment: Funny, I actually misread his question at first too and thought he wanted to place it on the ViewModel! Only now that you mentioned it and I re-read it, I spotted that. So your answer was actually correct before mine was. Upvoted as well :p

Comment: I talked to a aurelia dev and he said the same thing. Placing it in the route config doesn't work however. I will make a issue for it, thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

`activationStrategy` is a property of `RouterConfig`, which represents the route config object used by `config.map()`. I think that you need to set it on each route definition.

Example:

```js
configureRouter(config, router) {
  ...
  config.map([
    { 
      route: ['', 'home'],       
      name: 'home',       
      moduleId: 'home/index', 
      activationStrategy: 'invoke-lifecycle'
    }
  ]);
  ...
}
```

---

(Edit reason: I've made a terrible mistake by misreading your question at first, sorry :))

Comment: This does not seem to work w/Aurelia v1.0.0-rc.1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `config.options.compareQueryParams = true`.

[Changelog entry](https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/531eff10e790e67ced21c7e5a636b820217513b6/doc/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta120-2016-03-22)