# Aurelia doesn't 'refresh' vm when navigating

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Jolly good evening! In my Aurelia-App I'm using a viewModel to deal with various views via an navigationStrategy (reading out route-parameters and setting the view accordingly).

Navigation works baiscally well, there is one problem however:

When I keep navigating between routes that are based on the same viewModel, the viewModel doesn't 'refresh'. Only when navigating to a different route with a different viewModel first, and then back to the intended route, the contents are shown as expected.

It seems like the lifecycle-hooks of the component are not kicking in. Is there any way to trigger unbind() and detached() manually? Or is there a better way to do things generally?

Also the Route-Configuration seems a bit weird. When I'm taking away moduleId the app crashes, and when I'm taking away layoutViewModel the Data is not bound to the view. My Workaround for now is to assign an empty viewModel + an empty template. Am I using this wrong?

Big thanks!

```
configureRouter(config, Router) {

  var getModelStrat = (instruction) => {
    instruction.config.layoutView = "pages/templates/"+instruction.params.model+".html"
  }

  config.addAuthorizeStep(AuthorizeStep);
  config.title = 'Aurelia';
  config.map([
    {
      route: 'detail/:model/:id?',
      name: 'detail',
      moduleId: 'pages/empty',
      layoutViewModel: 'pages/detail',
      auth: true,
      navigationStrategy: getModelStrat
    },
    {...}
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. Router will try to reuse existing view models.

If you need to override this per view model, then create `determineActivationStrategy()` method on it and return `activationStrategy.replace`:

```js
import { activationStrategy } from 'aurelia-router';

export class SomeViewModel {
    // ...

    determineActivationStrategy() {
        return activationStrategy.replace;
    }

    // ...        
}
```

If you need to override this for each view model / route then take a look at [Marton Sagi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40001583/119230) for a similar question. Basically, all of your routes need to define `activationStrategy: 'replace'`.