# Aurelia routing to the same moduleID

Tags: aurelia

Hi there I have asked this on Gitter, but hope that someone here may be able to help.

I have two different routes that have the same moduleId. I have also set up a setting object within the routes with some data to differentiate what gets rendered. Everything works fine when I navigate to one of these routes from somewhere else, but if I navigate from one to the other neither the constructor or the activate are fired. am i missing something??

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999969/how-to-set-default-activationstrategy-in-aurelia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem and it took me a while to find a solution - this should help you I hope;

You need to add the `determineActivationStrategy()` method into your class, and then return as below.

```
import {activationStrategy} from "aurelia-router";

export class ExampleViewModel {

    determineActivationStrategy() {
        return activationStrategy.replace;
    }

}
```

This will force the VM to be replaced when you're routing to it from itself.

Here's some more info on the different Activation Strategy types;

> `activationStrategy.no-change` – reuse instance with no lifecycle events
>
> `activationStrategy.invokeLifecycle` – call lifecycle methods on the ViewModel instance each time the route switches
>
> `activationStrategy.replace` – construct new instance of ViewModel and invoke full lifecycle on it

Taken from here [ZombieCodeKill - Aurelia Routing Beyond the Basics](https://zombiecodekill.com/2016/07/03/aurelia-routing-beyond-the-basics/)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/467) :) Although not a complete fix out of the box, the  implementation is possible